# AngularJS routes not displaying the right view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a AngularJS/ExpressJS app and seem to be having a routing issue. `login.ejs` and `signup.ejs` are partial views, while `welcome.ejs` is the main template (that should load these views in a ui-view container). Ideally, `/welcome` would bring up the `welcome.ejs` page (the page already has login.ejs partial view code inside the container by default for the purpose of showing the user the login form at first). `/welcome/login` should bring up the login view on the `welcome` template (basically what shows up in `/welcome`) and `/welcome/signup` should bring up the `signup` view on the `welcome template. Instead, all URLs only show`/welcome` page (with login form).

**authController.js:**

```
var app = angular.module("myapp.controllers.auth", [
  "ui.router"
]);

app.config([
  "$stateProvider",
  "$locationProvider",
  function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("welcome", {
      url: "/welcome",
      templateUrl: "/welcome",
      controller: "AuthController",
    })
    .state("login", {
      parent: "welcome",
      url: "/login",
      views: {
        "container@": {
          templateUrl: "auth/login",
          controller: "AuthController"
        }
      }
    })
    .state("signup", {
        parent: "welcome",
        url: "/signup",
        views: {
          "container@": {
            templateUrl: "auth/signup",
            controller: "AuthController"
          }
        }
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
]);
```

**Relevant ExpressJS code:**

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.route(/\/welcome.*/)
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
    res.render("welcome");
  });
```

It has to be something small that I am overlooking, any pointers?

**EDIT: Adding HTML code**

**welcome.ejs:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ui-view="container" class="auth-container">
    <span>Sign in</span>
    <form ng-submit="login()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" autofocus>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
    </form>
    <a ui-sref="signup">Sign Up</a>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/controllers/authController.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/services/authService.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**auth/login.ejs**

```
<span>Sign in</span>
<form ng-submit="login()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
</form>
<a ui-sref="signup">Sign Up</a>
```

**auth/signup.ejs:**

```
<span>Sign Up</span>
<form ng-submit="signup()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn ban-primary">Sign Up</button>
</form>
<a ui-sref="login">Login</a>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `login` and `signup` be child states of `welcome`?

Comment: They are, I copied wrong...

Comment: Where is the HTML code with `ui-view="container"`?

Comment: I forgot to add those too. I've added it now.

Comment: Where is your root state template? The one with just `<div ui-view>` for your `welcome` state to populate? I'm starting to get the feeling `/welcome` is actually your app's main HTML file and you don't actually need a `welcome` state

Comment: That is supposed to be the root view container. Any view should be loaded in there. Everything outside `<div ui-view="container" class="auth-container">` is static.

Comment: You don't need a state for the root HTML file; typically `index.html` but in your case it appears to be `welcome.ejs`. Where are you loading script files via `<script>`?

Comment: Well, here is the thing. My main file is still index.ejs. But the application is not an SPA. It needs to be multipage, so as a result, I have "groups" of SPAs that exist for different parts of the app. I have edited the question to show the script part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as `/welcome` delivers your `welcome.ejs` file which represents the root state (typically `index.html`), you don't need a concrete `welcome` state. Your problem is arising because your URL re-writing to `welcome.ejs` via the `/\/welcome.*/` regex route requires that any state URLs under it require the `/welcome` prefix. Simply set up an *abstract* parent state to set the `/welcome` URL prefix.

```
$stateProvider.state('welcome', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/welcome'
}
.state("login", {
  parent: 'welcome',
  url: "/login",
  views: {
    "container@": {
      templateUrl: "auth/login",
      controller: "AuthController"
    }
  }
})
.state("signup", {
  parent: 'welcome',
  url: "/signup",
  views: {
    "container@": {
      templateUrl: "auth/signup",
      controller: "AuthController"
    }
  }
});
```

---

Alternatively, drop the `welcome` state and prefix all your state URLs with `/welcome`, eg

```
url: '/welcome/login'
```

Comment: That didn't make much of a difference. Both URLs still render `/wecome`

Comment: @DemCodeLines Assuming you mean `/welcome/login` and `/welcome/signup`, have you enabled HTML5 mode on `$locationProvider`? You would also need a `<base>` tag

Comment: Yup, it's enabled and I have set the base tag in `welcome.ejs`

Comment: @DemCodeLines where, I don't see it. What `href` does it have?

Comment: Edited the question above. It's set to `<base href="/">`

Comment: @DemCodeLines also, are you checking your browser console for errors and 404 requests for templates?

Comment: Yup, no 404's being reported. Although in the console, when I request for `/welcome/signup`, I see `GET /welcome 200`, a couple javascript files loading and then `GET /welcome 304`

Comment: @DemCodeLines you're probably running into this issue ~ https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-my-assets-and-templates-are-not-loading

Comment: This is weird. I have to set the base (and html5mode) as well as absolute URLs. Anyways, that accomplishes the task. Although it seems like a hackjob.

Comment: Without a `<base>`, I get a `$location:nobase` error

Comment: @DemCodeLines please check my answer again. I realised what was actually going on here. Sorry for making it more complex than it had to be